# Why does my Heroku Open App Button Not Work?

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, venmo

When in the Heroku development environment looking at my project, I click on the Open App button and the page never loads. I believe this is connected to a bug in my iOS application

I'm a beginning developer working on an iOS app that uses a Heroku server to interact with the Venmo SDK. I deployed the server (written in Node.js) successfully, but I'm new to that language and much of it was done with tutorials and sample code, so I'm not sure how a lot of it works.

I have a line of code that accesses the servers page (something along the lines of "xxxxxx-server.heroku-app.com", but it fails every time. Since the heroku app has successfully deployed, I think the fact that I can't open it is related to this error.

Below is a sample piece of my iOS application in Swift 4 that tries to access my server:

```swift
func fetchClientToken() {
        // TODO: Switch this URL to your own authenticated API
        let clientTokenURL = NSURL(string: "https://barhop-server.herokuapp.com/client_token")!
```

I expected this to work because this is the URL of my server. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.